# Reading in a file of one-word lines in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, file, file-upload, strip

Just curious if there's a cleaner way to do this. I have a list of words in a file, one word per line.
I want to read them in and pass each word to a function.
I've currently got this:

```
f = open(fileName,"r");
lines = f.readlines();
count = 0
for i in lines:
    count += 1
    print("--{}--".format(i.rstrip()))
    if count > 100:
        return
```

I there a way to read them in faster without using rstrip on each line?

Comment: What do you mean faster?  Why a return without a function? Do you always only want the first 100 lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fileName) as f:
    lines = (line for _, line in zip(range(100), f.readlines()))
    for line in lines:
        print('--{}--'.format(line.rstrip()))
```

This is how I would do it. Note the context manager (the `with/as` statement), and the generator comprehension giving us only the first 100 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48979132/7311767) answer:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i >= 100:
            break
        print("--{}--".format(line[:-1]))
```

If you don't an `.strip()` and know the length line terminator, you can use `[:-1]`.